# Spark Streaming - Count distinct element in state

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

I am having a dstream with a key-value pair of VideoID-UserID, what is a good practice of count a distinct UserID group by VideoID?

```
// VideoID,UserID
foo,1
foo,2
bar,1
bar,2
foo,1
bar,2
```

As above, I want to get VideoID-CountUserID by removing redundant `foo,1` and `bar,2` at any time, so the result should be:

```
foo: 2
bar: 2
```

In other words, I want to hold a big state dataset in memory. When a new batch of dstream arrives, compares it with the dataset to count the distinct users of every video.

How to do it?

I am working on Spark 1.6, but an answer of onward version is accepted. Python code if possible.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get distinct counts of userIDs grouped by video IDs consider using **aggregateByKey**. Sorry, this is Scala so you'll have to translate.

```
val rdd = sc.textFile("your_file.txt")

val initialSet = Set.empty[Int]
val addToSet = (s: Set[Int], v:Int) => s + v
val mergeSets = (s1: Set[Int], s2: Set[Int]) => s1 ++ s2

val distinctValSets = rdd.aggregateByKey(initialSet)(addToSet, mergeSets)
val distinctValCountd = rdd.map({case(k,s) => (k,s.size)})
```

Initial set is the initial value of your aggregation object, addToSet and mergeSets specify how to add values to your set and merge different sets based on key. This should give you the distinct amount of users associated with each video, and is cheaper (space-wise) than reduceByKey and groupByKey.

Comment: Thanks for spending time! Now I think it is not a good way to hold a big dataset in memory, so I use window function to count distinct in a period instead of it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
  val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(Seq(("foo", 1),("foo", 2),("foo", 1)))
  rdd1.groupByKey.mapValues(x=>x.toSet.toSeq).flatMapValues(x=>x).collect
```